# How to get string output using php?

Tags: php

I am using below code to get category one by one, but my code showing me at once all category. how to i get all category one by one or using array?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if($allCategories !== 0) { foreach($allCategories['Games'] as $games_cat){ 

echo $games_cat->category_name;
echo $games_cat->category_id;

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($games_cat->category_name);
var_dump($games_cat->category_id);
echo '</pre>';

}
}
?>
```

and var_dump result are here:

```
string(5) "Games"
string(4) "GAME"

string(6) "Action"
string(11) "GAME_ACTION"
```

This is category name: `string(6) "Action"` and this is category id: `string(11) "GAME_ACTION"`

I am tried like this:

```
echo $games_cat->category_name[1];
echo $games_cat->category_id[2];
```

but no output are showing.

Comment: You are doing a foreach on all of them, so its going to show all of them. Unclear what you are expecting, or wanting, as your description clashes with your subject.

Comment: Your `category_name` or `category_id` is not an array, its a string. You try to access an string with `category_name[1]` like an array and that fails.

Comment: Try `echo $allCategories['Games'][0]->category_name;` instead. It's the `$allCategories['Games']` that is the array.

Comment: I wants to get one category name.

Comment: You want to "get one category name" based on category_id?

Comment: yes, i wants category all but not at once, one by one, such as: [0] and [1] and [3]

Comment: @magnus-eriksson your code working.

Comment: Can you show us var_dump($allCategories); and what do you expect as an output?